# How to make a file receive location for a two way receive port?

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

I have a two way receive port with a receive location set up to use MLLP.  Everything gets bound to the receive port, so I wanted to create an additional receive location that I could use to manually drop files into, so that they would get processed by send ports and orchestrations just as if data can in through MLLP.  Ie, no

Is there any way you can do this, without having to update your send ports and orchestrations to also bind to another receive port?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The FILE adapter cannot be used in two-way receive ports. There was a discussion on this matter (asking why and suggesting that Microsoft make this possible) back in 2010 on the MSDN forums:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/biztalkgeneral/thread/A61EEE82-703A-4D74-AAA9-63467C42DD86